# Can association be used to filter data in rails where clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `ProjectItem` model and `ProjectItemTransaction` Model. I want to return all `project_items` where `project_item_transacations` have `SKU > 0`. How can I write this?

```
ProjectItem.where(project_item_transactions.sku > 0) ??
```

Comment: `ProjectItem.includes(:project_item_transacctions).where("project_item_transaction.sku > 0")`

Comment: What is difference between includes and join @Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the association name if it is same as table name, which means ultimately you will be using table name only.
As mentioned by @Fabio, the correct way of querying is with join to avoid cross join and duplicate records

```
ProjectItem.
  joins(:project_item_transactions).
  where("project_item_transactions.sku > ?", 0)
```

Comment: `join` -> `joins`, `project_item_transacctions` -> `project_item_transactions/project_item_transaction`, `project_item_transaction` -> `project_item_transactions`.